# How to do production deployment for vue app?

Tags: vue.js, web-deployment

How to do production deployment  for vue app?

I have created vue project(frontend) and **backend** api are developed using express.js , and now i want to do the **production deployment**, But not sure what is the procedure?

After running the ""**npm run build**"" command, i got the **dist** folder. Where it contains all sort of information required for the project.

Can anyone please tell me the steps for doing the ""production deployment""??

What is the further steps , to proceed with **production deployment**

**production deployment solution that requires a web server.** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing `npm run build`, you have successfully created a `dist` folder that contains your production website. Now you have to deploy it to either your own custom server or you can use services like Firebase Hosting, Vercel, Netlify, etc.

Comment: If want to deploy using the **own custom server** what is the procedure. and what is  **own custom server** and can you please name some custom server

Comment: own custom server like **winscp** ??

Comment: Can you please tell me **weather the production deployment that requires a web server** ??

Comment: by custom server I mean virtual cloud machines provided by DigitalOcean, AWS, GCP, Azure, Alibaba etc

Comment: but my recommendation would be to go for either Firebase Hosting, Vercel or Netlify... they offer quite good free plans which are most of the time enough for you needs

Comment: Thanks got it. and Can you please tell me weather the production deployment that requires a web server (true/false)

Comment: true, production requires a web server... a web server can be like cloud machine or service like Vercel

Comment: I am using the api's created in the backend (express.js) .  and created build in frontend. Now if i deploy app to services like **Netlify** (it will act as a static app right)? then will my api's work. (or) do i need to maintain both frontend/backend in single file and deploy

Comment: let's take both things separately... for express js you have to use **cloud machines only** like DigitalOcean, AWS etc...  nodejs apps have to be deployed to an active server... Netlify, Vercel work with static sites like build with VueJS... although if you wish to do it for free then you have to alter your express app to Netlify or Vercel functions standard

Comment: The answer should be more verbose like how to deploy a Vue app with a web server.